# How to get absolute imports to work in Python?

Tags: python, import, architecture, python-import, software-design

I know there are dozens of similar questions about Python imports, so I'll try to phrase it a bit differently. I'll spare you the details of the days of desperation that lie behind me, and instead approach the issue from a more general point of view: What does it take to make imports of the form `from package.module.submodule import SomeClass` work in Python 3.6 in 2018?

When I look into random modules of large Python projects like [Django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/signing.py), [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py) or [Twisted](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/src/twisted/internet/task.py) this seems to be the import pattern they all use, probably because it has the two benefits of a) making clear where an object comes from and b) keeping the actual invocation of that object short and clean.

I thought it can't be wrong to learn from these projects and tried to emulate this pattern in my own package – and as others before me I have run into the hell of circular imports.

Thankfully there are already a lot of posts on this topic, and their recommendations seem to fall into two broad categories:

1) Change the imports

A lot of suggestions go in the direction of using some other form of import syntax. Quite common seems to be the approach to avoid `from X.Y import Z` statements and instead rely only on `import X.Y` and then use `Y.Z()` in the code. Long story short, I have tried this and rewritten my entire package in that manner, and it didn't change anything. It also looks very unpythonic and ugly to me.

2) Fix the circular dependencies

That is the second family of recommendations, and I agree entirely that it would be preferable to dodge this issue entirely by employing good design from the start. The problem is that I don't really have a coherent idea how to do this.

My project is certainly not the pinnacle of excellent software design, but it's also not spaghetti code. It's ten modules in a single package (no submodules) of around 1000 lines of code in total. Each module has a single responsibility: One has the main function, one is a flask instance, another one an API client, another one has all the data models and so on. To me its seems pretty much unavoidable that the imports between these modules (not the classes themselves) sometimes end up being circular. I have of course tried to break these circles (they are usually four or five modules long), but that always leads to other circles, if not immediately, then five commits later.

Now, I'm just a second year CS student and I'm entirely willing to accept that this might just be a point where I still have to learn much, much more. But to start with that it would be really helpful if someone could explain how this problem is dealt with in some of these larger projects mentioned above. Shouldn't they run into circular imports all the time? How do they prevent contributors from introducing a circle somewhere accidentally? Do they constantly refactor there codebase when they find out that an import isn't possible because it would lead to a circle? What's the general approach here?